# getting error on passing array to function in C

Tags: arrays, c, function

I have tried to use function to calculate the sum of elements in array. Logic is correct but I think there is some syntax error but I am not getting it. Please help me in solving this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int add(int arr[]);

int main(void)
{
    int nums[] = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 };
    int result = add(nums);
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}

int add(int arr[])
{
    int total = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

The error I am facing is this -> 
main.c:16:27: warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘arr’ will return size of ‘int *’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument] for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++) { ^ main.c:12:13: note: declared here int add(int arr[]) ^~~ Result: 3

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` worked on a function argument does not get the size of the array, but the size of the pointer that it decays to.

Comment: main.c:16:27: warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘arr’ will return size of ‘int *’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
     for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++) {
                           ^
main.c:12:13: note: declared here
 int add(int arr[])
             ^~~
Result: 3

Comment: @WeatherVane then how to get the size of an array in the add() function?

Comment: You must pass the number of elements as another function argument (or use a sentinel value). Your computation would have worked if done on the array itself in `main` as shown in the dup.

Comment: @CodeWithFaraz Edit error text into your that into your question. (it'll preserve the newline, unlike comments)

Comment: Pass the 10 as extra parameter. BTW 2**10 - 1.

Comment: And this is why C blows my mind. Why don't they just package the array size as part of the array? Everyone is going to be hand-rolling that the same way, for themselves

Comment: @Alexander One of the designers of C called zero terminated strings the greatest error. Also an array problem. Pascal solved it better.

Comment: @Alexander C has no packaging for strings either, which rely on a sentinel NUL marker.

Comment: @WeatherVane At least they have that, and don't rely on you mindlessly passing the string size around everywhere (though you still do need to do that, if you're going to be writing into the string)

Comment: @Alexander the array argument `*argv[]` passed to `main` uses both the number of elements as a separate argument `argc` *and* a sentinel value, in this case the `NULL` pointer.

Comment: guys, stay focused :P